# Use same loop to iterate over multiple arrays subsequently?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

Not looking for `zip()`, as I have multiple arrays:

```
var cellphones = [IPhone(), Galaxy()]
var laptops = [Macbook(), Ideapad()]
```

And I want to iterate over them all in any order:

```
cellphones.forEach { device in
    var multiple = lines()
    ofCode()
    thatDontNeedToKnowIfPhoneOrLaptop(device)
}
laptops.forEach { device in
    var multiple = lines()
    ofCode()
    thatDontNeedToKnowIfPhoneOrLaptop(device)
 }
```

How would I do this without having to repeat the loop bodies?

Comment: What about creating a closure/func with the repeated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the objects on the array all implement the same `protocol` or inherit the same class I believe this would work:

```
let loop: ((DeviceProtocol) -> Void) = { device in
    var multiple = lines()
    ofCode()
    thatDontNeedToKnowIfPhoneOrLaptop(device)
}

cellphones.forEach(loop)
laptops.forEach(loop)
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually solves my problem even better than the solution I asked for